# MongoDB scala driver: what is a best way to return Future when working with Observer callbacks?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I am writing a simple blog on Play Framework and MongoDB using Scala driver.
So it works and I'm happy but feel like my code is not good enough.
Could you guys review the following snippet which is one of my mongo service methods and tell me if there is a way to make it more clean:

```
def findByTitle(title:String)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext):Future[Option[Document]] = {
    val collection = db.getCollection("items")
    val results = collection.find(equal("title", title))
    val contentPromise: Promise[Option[Document]] = Promise()
    results.subscribe(new Observer[scala.Document] {
      var empty: Boolean = true
      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Error")

      override def onComplete(): Unit = {
        if (empty) contentPromise.success(None)
      }

      override def onNext(result: scala.Document): Unit = {
        empty = false
        contentPromise.success(Some(result))
      }
    })
    contentPromise.future
  }
```

I decided to return `Future[Option[Document]]` since there could be a chance that there is nothing by provided title. As far as the only way to work with `Observable` is via `Observer` callbacks I need to declare a `Promise` and then fulfill that promise in the `onComplete()` callback. To handle the case when there is no document by provided title I have no choice other than declaring this `var empty: Boolean = true` variable and then using it in `onNext()` and `onComplete()` callbacks.

Question: Is there a better way to approach this without using `var` inside my `Observer` instance?

Comment: Or you can use [that](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it would be far easier to work with a `Future[T]` instead of an observable:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits._

def findByTitle(title: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[Document]] = {
  val collection = db.getCollection("it")
  collection.find(equal("title", title))
            .toFuture()
            .recoverWith { case e: Throwable => { Log(e); Future.failed(e) } }
            .map(_.headOption)
}
```

The `T` in the future is actually a `Seq[T]`. This way a simple check can eliminate the need for mutable state.

Comment: Brilliant, Yuval. Thanks a lot. I did not know there is this 'toFuture' method

Comment: For the sake of correctness it should be though
`toFuture().map{seq => if(seq.isEmpty) None else Some(seq.head)}`
You can pattern match future's `value` as Option[Try[T]], but not the future itself if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @AlexanderArendar You're completely right, I mixed the `Try` API with the `Future` API, my bad.

Comment: I also added logging of possible error to your code

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov could you mention where you found out about that `toFuture` method?
Awesome find, I sure didn't come across :(
Seems like it could use some more pointers to it's documentation out here on the interwebz :)

Comment: [found it!](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.0/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable.html#toFuture():scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[T]])

Comment: @practechal I added the implicit import for future use :)

Comment: ```.toFuture.map(_.headOption)``` will first collect the entire sequence from the observable (until it completes) and then take head. This can be tremendously slow for large collections. ```.head.map(Option(_))``` might be more efficient.

Comment: why not just `find(...).headOption()`?